# Problema con pseudoclase hover

Tags: html5, css3

Espero darme a entender...

A unas imágenes les agregué **:hover** con parámetro **opacity:** 60%. Por otra parte, el **header** donde tengo el menú superior, tiene el parámetro **position: fixed**.

Cuando doy scroll hacia abajo con el mouse y dejo una parte de la imagen debajo del header, el header oculta esa parte de la imagen, es como si esa parte de la imagen quedara debajo del header, hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema es cuando paso el mouse por encima de esa imagen que se muestra incompleta, se activa el hover, haciendo que toda la imagen se vea. La parte de la imagen que cubría el  header, ahora se ve encima de este, y eso se ve muy mal.

¿Cómo sería posible que aunque pasara el mouse encima de la imagen, sólo se aplicara el hover a la parte de la imagen que es visible?

Anexo imagenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda ver el código CSS y HTML para poder ayudarte mejor en vez de imágenes.

Comment: Hola @0M1N1D0, como dice Luis Fernando. Debes proporcionar tu código para que nosotros podamos revisarlo e indicarte dónde se encontraba el problema Hasta el momento, de acuerdo a lo que has descrito, apunta a que tienes la propiedad `z-index` en tu selector `.selector:hover { z-index: _valor_ }`. Por ahora, podríamos suponer eso, pero necesitamos el código para ayudarte. Recuerda consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agregar el `z-index: 2 /* AL HEADER */`
Agrega el `z-index: 1 /* A LA IMAGEN :HOVER */`

Si te sigue ocurriendo lo mismo agregar `Position:relative /* A LA IMAGEN */`

Comment: Pon el código css html para poder ayudarte

Comment: Yo intentaría usar el clear: both; para limpiar el flotado  si es eso que lo deseas